# Suddenly FirebaseMessagingService is not working

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging

I know that getTOken(); is depreciated. and I've implemented the new way to generate token which mentioned here. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

```
FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```

But still not working and getting error :

```
E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
```

here is my Manifest.xml regarding FCM.

```
    <service android:name="Server.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>


    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/hint" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
        android:value="ac065fa4fd7ecf48b4fe2b391d25bcc416e85b2d" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
        android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />
```

and here is my messing class:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onNewToken(String s) {
    super.onNewToken(s);
    sendRegistrationToServer(s);
    Utils.setPreference(this, Utils.key_gcmToken, s);
    Log.e("Atiar - MyFirebaseMS = ", "New token Generated: " + s);
}
```

Also note that google play service is enabled: [image]

Comment: Alright, thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @AtiarTalukdar are you using simulator? If Yes then try with another  simulator.

Comment: @FaysalAhmed I'm using Real device )

Comment: The error message SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE is generally seen when there is a issue with internet connection. Check the connectivity.